# Name of animated series from recent past

Tags: story-identification, tv

When I was little (about 8-9 years ago), I watched an animated series whose name I can't remember, but I really liked the series so I want help to find its name.
I can't remember the media source, but I watched them in Bulgarian.

In the series there was a purple boy (he wore loose purple trousers and had purple hair), I think his name was Strack or something like that, and there were some kind of monsters, that could be summoned by gems. There were other kids too and they were Strack's friends and еach one had a gem. I remember a big forest too.

It's not much information, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Info should include at least 1. When did you watch it? 2. Which language? 3. Which TV channel or other media source?

Comment: The first sounds a little like [Dave the Barbarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_the_Barbarian), but then again, it could be anything

Comment: I'm not sure enough to answer this, but it might be Monster Allergy. Baggy purple-ish protagonist with monsters and gems.

Answer (score 3):

Paul above [commented that it might be](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137825/name-of-animated-series-from-recent-past#comment349571_137825) *[Monster Allergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Allergy_(TV_series))*, a 2006 animated series following a young man named **Zick** with purple hair and pants. Summary from Wikipedia:

> The series follows 12-year-old Ezekiel Zick (called Zick) who suffers from all sorts of allergies (though people call that an excuse) and discovers that he has the ability to see the invisible monsters that live among us. Along with help of his best friend Elena Potato (called Erlinee) and his talking cat, Timothy, Zick hopes to hone his powers to one day become a Monster Tamer just like his dad, Zob Zick.

[image: dvd cover]

It's based off of the [Disney Italy comic book series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Allergy).

Answer (score 3):

thanks for the suggestions and sorry for the late update - I found the series, it's Magi Nation. Had to search a lot though

Comment: Can you add to matching details, and how you went about finding it? It might help other people looking for it.

Comment: You can also accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.