# Cartoon about a boy and his friends capturing monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I'm trying to remember a cartoon where a boy and his few friends went around capturing monsters. When they captured one, they always put the monster in some sort of glass container. They had a collection and if I remember correctly, they would always give the monster to a scientist.

That's all I remember, but it was an awesome show, please help me remember it!

Comment: Sounds like... Pokémon!

Comment: When did you watch this cartoon?

Comment: What's this Pokemon thing? Never heard of it. Must be a rip-off of Yugioh! Capsule Monsters.

Answer (score 5):

As per Des's deleted post (I'll yield to them if they come back) this could be *[Monster Allergy](http://www.monsterallergy.com/index_en.php)*, a 2005 animated adaptation of the comic book of the same name.

[image: Monster Allergy splash page]

> The series follows 12-year-old Ezekiel Zick (called Zick) who suffers from various allergies and has the ability to see the invisible monsters that live among us. Along with help of his best friend, Elena Potato and his talking cat, Timothy, Zick hopes to hone his powers to one day become a Monster Tamer just like his dad, Zobedja Zick.

They place the monsters in "Taming Boxes" like the following:
[image: Taming Box] [image: More Taming Boxes]

I don't believe there's a scientist character they interact with *per se*, but Zick's mother, [Greta Barrymore](http://monsterallergy.wikia.com/wiki/Greta_Barrymore), is a Keeper. That might be who you're thinking of.

[image: Greta Barrymore]

### Trailer

Comment: If so, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137825/name-of-animated-series-from-recent-past/138801#138801

Comment: Yuppp!!! This is the one! Thank you very much! ^^^

Comment: @Kristups: If you wouldn't mind clicking the checkmark beside the voting buttons to accept it, that would help us a lot and you'll get points for it as well.

Answer (score 1):

In *[The Secret Saturdays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Saturdays)* (2008-2010) the Saturday family secretly traveled the globe studying cryptids, keeping them secret from ordinary people, and fighting various super villains.

[image: Front cover of The Secret Saturdays box]

The series had a crossover with *Ben 10: Omniverse*.

I don't remember the Saturdays collecting cryptids in every episode, but they did have some cryptid pets and companions.

Anyway, it is possible that this might be the series you seek.

Answer (score -1):

Could be Pokemon. Could also be Monster Hunter.  There was also the one with caveman, the good scientists brought him back from some stone slab, the bad scientists brought back lots of dinosaurs, he catches them for good scientists by bashing monsters on the head with a club. Can't remember the name of that one. Remember the starting song, it had "hoom daga, hin daga" refrain.

Comment: You may thinking of [Flint the Time Detective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint_the_Time_Detective), although the scientists hunted magical creatures, not dinosaurs.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been looking for that show for ages! It was translated (roughly) as Super Caveman and  in my country (main character's name was translated as Cavemano :( ) and I never learned the true name until today. Thank you very much.