# Cartoon - boy traps monsters into balls on a magical bracelet

Tags: story-identification, magic, anime, cartoon

As a kid, I used to watch this cartoon show about a boy who captured monsters like giant spiders and put them in these tiny balls, and then summoned them using some kind of magical bracelet. He'd battle with his friends using these monsters. It sounds like Pokemon but it isn't. I don't know what it's called and it would mean the world to me if anyone can find it.

Comment: Might it be “Yo-Kai Watch”? I don’t know anime well, but it sort of fits the description.

Comment: A more precise time reference (in the 90s? 2000-something? three months ago?) could really help finding the right cartoon amid all the existing ones.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/162103/66252) ?

Comment: it was back in 2008-10 on this arabic channel mbc3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be the animated series [Spider Riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_Riders), a Canadian-Japanese co-production which first aired in 2006. The protagonist of this series is a boy who finds his way into a hollow earth type secret world. A mysterious bracelet called a "[Manacle](http://spiderriders.wikia.com/wiki/Manacle)" attaches itself to his wrist:

[image]

For those who are able to use them, these Manacles allow a person to summon and control a "[Battle Spider](http://spiderriders.wikia.com/wiki/Spiders)":

[image] [image]

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBC_3), this series aired on MBC 3, as mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Yes this is it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

This may be one of the [Bakugan series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakugan_Battle_Brawlers), which aired from 2007 through 2012. I can't confirm whether it was aired on MBC 3, but there are clips of an Arabic dub available online.

In Bakugan, monsters are stored in small balls:

[image]

There are several Bakugan monsters which look like four-, six-, or eight-legged spider-creatures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Throughout the series, there are a variety of bracelet-like devices used by the heroes and their opponents to monitor and control their Bakugan battles:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am certain It’s called Spider riders about a boy who get transported to another would and he help them battle evil on a battle spider

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! I'm afraid I don't see how this adds anything to the accepted answer from 2 1/2 months ago.

Comment: @F1Krazy an answer doesn't _need_ to provide anything different to previous answers, although it'll usually be accused of copying etc. if it does.