# Pokemon-like anime with watches instead of Pokeballs

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I am searching for an anime/cartoon that is like Pokemon, but they use watches instead of Pokeballs.

The protagonist is red-haired and has a "Pokemon" that looks like a Fire Geodude, and has two friends; a girl with brown hair and a boy with blue hair. He has a third friend that always "fights" him.

Please help; I watched it around 2012, and can confirm that it isn't Yo-kai Watch.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: How do they use the watches? How old are characters? What are their names? Did they have distinctive clothes?, etc

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour], or you can [edit] in additional details that will help us figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be *[Spider Riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_Riders)* as per [Cartoon - boy traps monsters into balls on a magical bracelet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184657/cartoon-boy-traps-monsters-into-balls-on-a-magical-bracelet)?

> The protagonist of this series is a boy who finds his way into a hollow earth type secret world. A mysterious bracelet called a "Manacle" attaches itself to his wrist:
>
> [image: Image of Hunter wearing his "Manacle"]
>
> For those who are able to use them, these Manacles allow a person to summon and control a "Battle Spider":

The character list includes multiple companions including a brown-haired girl and a blue-haired boy.

[image: Image for season 1]

One confounding factor is that their summoned creatures look distinctly spider-like, not like a fiery Geodude.

[image: Image of Hunter beside his spider]