# Need help remembering show about a boy with blue hair, involving monsters

Tags: story-identification

I was wondering if you could help me remember this one show I watched as a kid. I believe it's from the late 90s to the early 2000s, about this boy with blue hair and a pinkish face that had something to do with monsters. Whether he could talk to them or turn into them, I don't remember. I also remember scenes of his bedroom where his bed was on the left side.

I've looked for hours on the internet and can't seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Animated or live action? Which language was it in? Was it dubbed? Was it a comedy? Any info is welcome!

Comment: Which country did you see it in? Did you have cable or was it on network broadcast? Do you remember other shows you might have watched at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be *[Monster Allergy](http://www.monsterallergy.com/index_en.php)*, an animated series made from a Italian comic that started in 2005. The principal character, Zick, has blue hair, and is allergic to Monsters - he's also one of the few in his world that can see them. He can talk to them and as some of them are nice, they live with him.

[image: Monster Allergy splash page]

Comment: If so, we have the same show mentioned at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137825/name-of-animated-series-from-recent-past/138801#138801 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/162155/23243 (where it was confirmed, but not accepted, by the querent)